# Application on Gronwall's inequality

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, stability-theory

Using Gronwall' inequality, I need to show that the solution of the following initial value problem

$x'(t)=(1-a \cos{t})x$, $x(0)=x_0$

satisfies $|x(t)| \leq |x_0| e^{(1+a)t} $.

Here, $0<a<1$.

Gonwall's inequality says: if $g(t)$ is continuous real valued function with $g(t) \geq 0$ and

$g(t) \leq C+K \int_{0}^t g(s) ds $ for all $0 \leq t \leq a$ then we have
$g(t) \leq C e^{Kt}$.

My work,

The solution of the initial value problem is
$x(t)=C \exp{(t-a \sin t)}$. Then I tried to take $g(t)=\exp{(t-a \sin t)}$ but I couldn't apply the inequality to get the required result. Any idea what $g(t)$ should be taken?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably too simple as one can, as you did, easily write down the exact solution.

What was intended was to get the estimate
$$
|1-a\cos(t)|\le 1+|a| 
$$
and the apply Grönwall to the differential inequality
$$
|x'|\le (1+a)|x|
$$
which results in the claimed bound.

Note that ($t>0$, $a>0$)
$$
|\sin t|\le\min(|t|,1)\le |t|\implies t-a\sin t\le (1+a)t
$$
is a very wide upper bound